# Easiest method of displaying how many instances for each hour?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, database, pivot-table

I have a call log which has thousands of calls in it. Each call is an entry in a CSV file which includes a datetime stamp.

[image: Screenshot example of data]

What I would like to be able to do, is easily view how many calls there are at each hour of the day.

For example:

01:00    0 Calls
02:00    0 Calls
...
13:00    9 Calls
...
etc.

Is there a function within Excel that could achieve this? If not, what is the simplest way of achieving this?

Comment: *Is there a function within Excel that could achieve this?* `COUNTIFS()`

Comment: You could also use a pivot table.

Answer (score 0):

SUMPRODUCT should help you with this.    Please see the sample below.

[image]

The formula if you want to copy it and change references.

=SUMPRODUCT(--(HOUR(A$2:A$12)=B2))

I hope this helps,

Brad

Answer (score 0):

*Following method will help you to count per day instance of hours.*

[image]

- Formula in cell `J2`:

  ```
  =SUMPRODUCT((MOD($E$2:$E$12,1)>=H2)*(MOD($E$2:$E$12,1)<= I2)*(INT($E$2:$E$12)=$G$2))
  ```

**N.B.**

- Keep changing the **D**ate in Cell `G2` to count next day instances.
- Alter Time instances in column `H` & `I`, if and when required.
- You may adjust cell references in the formula as needed.